# How do I scope through a model that's somewhat part of the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't comprehend how I would scope through a child using a model that isn't fully associated with it. The main model being Kid and the other being Favorite. In the app, a user can have Favorite moms and a Kid belongs to a mom and a dad. Mom and Dad don't belong to anything:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mom
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dad
  belongs_to :mom
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :favorites
end
```

As you can see, a Favorite doesn't have any association to Kid. I'm guessing it would if I made it go through each other like favorite.kids or kid.favorites but the latter doesn't make sense to me because of what I want to do with it.

What I want to do is create a scope that list a dads' kids but only for the ones that are a user's favorite moms. So something like:

```
@dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
@kids = @dad.kids.current_users_favorite_moms
```

But which model what I start on Favorites? Dad? Mom? I'm not sure. Could you help me?

Comment: so the main thing is a kid, he has a dad, and a mom, and a favorite mom ? and what's a user?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I edited my question to include the `User` model. And yes, the kid is the main thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't understand the relation between the `Kid` and the `User` so I'm gonna drop it.

I think it would be easier if you used `has_many :through`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorite_moms, through: :favorites, class_name: :mom
end
Class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad
end
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mom
end
```

Then we'd do this

```
@dad = Dad.find(id)
@kids = Kid.where(dad: @dad, mom: current_user.favorite_moms)
```

Try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks. Just has to change `class_name: 'Mom'` to `source: :mom`. I'm guessing because I'm using `rails 4.1.1`.